# Probability of getting at least N successes before either F failures or reaching T trials

Tags: probability

How do you calculate the odds of getting **AT LEAST** `N` successes before **EITHER** getting `F` failures **OR** reaching `T` trials?

For example, if I want to find the odds of getting 3-to-8 successes before 3 failure out of a maximum of 10 events; in other words, we stop at the 10th event regardless of if we have had 3 failures or not.

Comment: Can you tell us what you have tried, or what aspect of the question is puzzling you ?

Comment: How is **T** related to **N** and **F** ? Or is the concrete example you have given also bothering you ?

Comment: I have updated my OP to clarify. I have looked at the standard probability formulae (binomial probability, Hypergeometric distribution etc) and cannot figure out a way to apply any of them to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

"I want to find the odds of getting 3-to-8 successes before 3 failure out of a maximum of 10 events; in other words, we stop at the 10th event regardless of if we have had 3 failures or not."

Taking your clarification, and assuming "odds" has been loosely used for "probability, let the probabilities of success and failure in a trial be *p* and *q* respectively.

We shall divide the computation into two parts:

Getting $3$ successes before $3$ failures, can be modelled as a tennis match, in which first to three sets (which is same as best of five) is the winner.

We can use the binomial distribution as  Pr = $\binom50 q^0p^5 + \binom51q^1p^4 + \binom52q^2p^3$

At this stage, we have three cases for wins: $5-0, 4-1,\;and\; 3-2\,$ and a maximum of $5$ more matches to be played, stopping at $3$ failures

For the $3-2$ case, eg the total probability will be given by
$[\binom52q^2p^3][q + pq + p^2q +p^3q + p^4q +p^5]$

Work out similarly for the other cases and add up